# Difference in the digits of a 3 digit number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was working on a problem: "Find the number of those 3-digit numbers the digits of which are in increasing order and satisfying the following condition: the difference of any two consecutive digits is at least 2." I tried finding a pattern in the numbers and I ended up with a result of 56. However, I am not certain whether this is correct. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: People are answering your questions, but you are not kind to reward their effort by upvoting and accepting their answers. Could you?

Answer (score 0):

I find fewer such numbers, starting with $135$ and ending with $579$.  Only six of them start with the digit $3$.

> In fact, I find $35$ such numbers.

I only get $56$ if I pretend that $024$ is a three digit number.